# Flexbox layout not working as intended

Tags: css, flexbox

i have this HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-full">1</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex">2</div>
    <div class="flex">3</div>
    <div class="flex">4</div>
</div>
```

Styled by this CSS

```
    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
    .flex-container{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 960px;
        display: flex;
        background-color: lightgray;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-full{
        background-color: red;
        flex: 1 0 100%;
    }
    .flex{
        background-color: blue;
        flex: 1 0 90px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .flex-container {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .flex-container {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

But the result is not as intended. i will try to give a visual presentation of the problem(upload image wont work):

On screen width 320px and below, i get the following result

```
    111111111111111
    222222233333333
    444444444444444
```

What i expected was:

```
    phone screen          bigger screen
    111111111111111       111111111111111111
    222222222222222       222222333333444444
    333333333333333
    444444444444444
```

I hope it made sence, please help me out :)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yv7yzfpr/)

Comment: For second div flex-container, you can play with flexDirection column for phone(max-width: 480px) and flexDirection row for bigger screen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for `flex-direction: column;`?

on .flex-container.

Comment: No, i want first row (11111) to always fill the space, and i want second row (222,333,444) to either be next to eachother, or ontop of eachother, never split into a row of 2 and a row of 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Flex, you may use `justify-content` and `align-content` for horizontal and vertical alignment, respectively.

Also `flex-basis` takes the same values as the width and height properties, and specifies the initial main size of the flex item, before free space is distributed according to the flex factors.

```
.flex-container {
  flex-direction:         row;
  justify-content:        space-between;
  align-content:          space-between;
}

.flex1, .flex4{
  flex-basis:             100%;
}

.flex2, .flex3{
  flex-basis:             50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){

  .flex2, .flex3{
    flex-basis:             100%;
  }

}
```

You may also use `width: 100%` and `width: 50%` instead if `flex-basis`.

Comment: I have edited to clarify my goal, i wish for the .flex to have the same CSS

Comment: So whats the problem with answer?

Comment: First of all, i feel changing flex properties in media query is counter intuitive to the usage of flexbox. Secondly, flex 2, 3 and 4 should be on the same row when not on top of each other.